# Central Limit Theorem for Difference-in-Means Estimator

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

I am studying Lecture 1 of [Stefan Wager's Causal Inference notes](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eswager/stats361.pdf) and come across a central limit theorem for the difference-in-means estimator, which I am unable to prove.

The mathematical abstraction is as follows. Let $W_1,...,W_n$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables. Let $(Y_1(0),Y_1(1)),...,(Y_n(0),Y_n(1))$ be i.i.d. random vectors. Moreover, assume that $\{W_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{(Y_i(0),Y_i(1))\}_{i=1}^n$ are independent. Let $n_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n W_i$ and $n_0=n-n_1$, which are both random variables. The *difference-in-means estimator* is
$$
\widehat{\tau} = \frac{1}{n_1}\sum_{i=1}^nW_iY_i - \frac{1}{n_0}\sum_{i=1}^n(1-W_i)Y_i.
$$
Define $\tau  =\mathbb{E}[Y_1(1)-Y_1(0)]$. On the top of page 5, the author states the following:

> A standard central limit theorem can be used to verify that
> $$
> \begin{align}
> & \sqrt{n}(\widehat{\tau}-\tau)\Rightarrow\mathcal{N}(0,V), \\[4pt]
> & V = \text{var}(Y_i(0)) / \mathbb{P}(W_i=0) + \text{var}(Y_i(1)) / \mathbb{P}(W_i=1).
> \end{align}
> $$

**My question:** How to prove this rigorously?

**My thoughts:** Some useful properties of $\widehat{\tau}$ are
$$
\begin{align}
& \mathbb{E}\left[\widehat{\tau}\mid\{(Y_i(0),Y_i(1))\}_{i=1}^n,n_1\right] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i(1)-Y_i(0)), \\[4pt]
&\text{var}(\widehat{\tau}\mid n_1) = \frac{1}{n_0}\text{var}(Y_i(0)) + \frac{1}{n_1}\text{var}(Y_i(1)).
\end{align}
$$
These two results are stated in pages 3 and 4 in the notes, and I am able to prove them rigorously. By the first equality, $\mathbb{E}\widehat{\tau}=\tau$. Intuitively, for $n$ large, $\sqrt{n}(\widehat{\tau}-\tau)$ approximates a zero-mean normal random variable with variance
$$
(\sqrt{n})^2\text{var}(\widehat{\tau}\mid n_1) = \frac{\text{var}(Y_i(0))}{n_0/n} + \frac{\text{var}(Y_i(1))}{n_1/n} \to \frac{\text{var}(Y_i(0))}{\mathbb{P}(W_i=0)} + \frac{\text{var}(Y_i(1))}{\mathbb{P}(W_i=1)}.
$$
However, the standard central limit theorem does not really apply because we are adding *dependent* random variables $(W_n/n_1-(1-W_i)/n_0)Y_i$, $1\le i\le n$.

Alternatively, I could apply central limit theorem to $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nW_iY_i$ and the strong law of large numbers to $n_1/n$, and use Slutsky's Theorem to combine them, then do the same for $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(1-W_i)Y_i$ and $n_0/n$. But then it is not clear how to deduce the weak limit of their difference $\widehat{\tau}$.